# Does playing advantage count as a restart in football?

Tags: rules, football

According to Law-5, the referee cannot change the restart decision once the play restarted. He/she can only issue disciplinary action for the events happened before the restart. In this context, does referee's decision of playing the advantage count as a restart?

Answer (score 2):

No. Play has not been stopped - that is the entire purpose of advantage.

Neither has a restart occurred. Law 8, *Introduction* lists all restarts of play. For completeness, they are

- Kick-off
- Free kick (direct or indirect)
- Penalty kick
- Throw-in
- Goal kick
- Corner kick
- Dropped ball